# Changing the constant in Vitali's Covering theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Vitali's Covering Theorem : Let E be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ . Assume that $F$ is a collection of open balls which are centered at points of $E$ such that every point of $E$ is the center of some ball in $F$ . Then there exists a sequence ( possibly terminating) $B_1,B_2,\ldots$ of balls from $F$ such that 
a.) The balls $B_1, B_2,\ldots$ are disjoint 
b.) $E\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\geq 1} 3B_{\alpha}$

Here is the question that I am working on ,

E = (-1,1). For $x\in E$ , $r(x) = (1+2|x|)/3$ and $B_x = (x-r(x),x+r(x))$. Let $F= {(B_x | x\in E)}$. 
Prove that the conculsion of above mentioned Vitali theorem does not hold if the factor 3 is replaced by 2.

My attempt : So far I have only been able to see that,  each ball in F covers the point zero , but I do not know how to use this to answer the question .